# Set Guile as default Geiser REPL in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, guile

How do I configure Emacs to set Guile as the default Scheme implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `geiser-default-implementation`, or if you only want guile set the `geiser-actve-implementations` to `'(guile)`.

Comment: That was it! I just did `(setf geiser-active-implementations '(guile))` and it worked.